# How to get all packages listed in a PPA at once?

Tags: 14.04, ppa, gcc

For example, if I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
```

I get gcc-5 but not gfortran-5 or cpp-5 or any of the other packages [listed here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test/+sourcepub/4959796/+listing-archive-extra). How to get all of those packages at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via <kbd>Y-PPA-Manager</kbd>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

---

1. **Start <kbd>Y-PPA-Manager</kbd> and select <kbd>Manage PPAs</kbd>**

   [image]
2. **Select your PPA and click <kbd>List packages</kbd>**

   [image]
3. **See the packages and install what you need via <kbd>Install</kbd>**

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

This `awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*ubuntu-toolchain-r*test*Packages > to_install.txt` will put all the packages into a text file.

You can manually edit this file to remove anything unwanted and use that file to feed it to `apt-get` like `for i in $(cat to_install.txt); do sudo apt-get install $i; done`.  This last part will probably be a bad idea without confirming these packages are not conflicting with other packages in the PPA.

---

The normal way to do is write them out. So ...

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5 gfortran-5 gnat-5
```

after having a quick look at the packages to see if they might have conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had no idea. So I will install them selectively.

Comment: Pick the ones you need, have a quick look at the dependencies and than make a one-liner ;)